# Joysticks priority setting

Tags: joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to set up a priority between two joysticks which from different computers to control a robot.
Now, the robot will follow the latest signal come from the joysticks. I want to set a main joystick and a second joystick.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200436/joysticks-priority-setting/) by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-01-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2015-01-06**:
Are you using them to send cmd_vel twist messages?

**Comment by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on 2015-01-06**:
Yes, I have a node to subscribe the topic "joy",
So I'm thinking is it possible to edit the joy_node to public different topic name? like joy1 joy2
I found  /opt/ros/groovy/share/joy but I dont know how to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use a launch file to assign different namespaces to the nodes as shown in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch) under 1.4.2.  Also, you can use [cmd_vel_mux](http://wiki.ros.org/cmd_vel_mux) which allows you to assign priority levels to cmd_vel messages which will block conflicting messages by dropping one with lower priority.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on 2015-01-06**:
Thank you very much, I'm trying with these.
Really Really Thanks.